# How get X and Y position of Title on Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I need get X and Y position of Title on NavBar. Title set through Storyboard.
I have tried:

`let titleXPosition: CGFloat? = self.navigationItem.titleView?.bounds.origin.x`

But `bounds.origin.y` returns `nil`. How i can get X and Y position? Thanks.

Comment: If you simply set the `title` (and not the `titleView`), then there is no public API to tell you the frame of the title.

Comment: `bounds` will always be 0.. You need to use `titleView.frame` which is its position relative to its parent.. and if you need it's position relative to another view, you need to do `titleView.superview.convertRect(from: titleView.frame, toView: someViewOrNil)`

Comment: @Brandon I think you missed the part where `titleView` is `nil`.

Comment: @rmaddy if i set title through code i will have public API for frame position?

Comment: @Bandyliuk No. It doesn't matter how you set the `title`, there is no public API to get the title's frame. `titleView` will be `nil` unless you actually set the `titleView`. If you want, and you do it carefully, you can dig into the private subview structure of the `UINavigationBar` and find the `UILabel` (or maybe some undocumented class) that represents the title. But such code could fail on any iOS update.